# Unable to create relation table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm kinda new to postgresql so I'm having problems with simple things like creating relations between tables.

In this exercise I'm unable to insert the information into the relation table Plays.

All I get are empty query's and I'm getting kinda desperate.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Actor CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Actor (
    id_actor SERIAL,
    name     VARCHAR, 
    fb_likes INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_actor)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Movie CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Movie 
(
    id_movie SERIAL, 
    title VARCHAR, 
    duration INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_movie)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plays CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Plays (
    id_actor           SERIAL, 
    id_movie           SERIAL, 
    is_main_character  BOOLEAN,  
    FOREIGN KEY (id_actor) REFERENCES Actor (id_actor), 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_movie) REFERENCES Movie (id_movie)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Imported;
CREATE TABLE Imported (
    title             VARCHAR,
    duration          INTEGER,
    name              VARCHAR,
    fb_likes          INTEGER,
    is_main_character BOOLEAN
);

COPY Imported FROM '/Applications/movie.csv' DELIMITER ';' csv header;

INSERT INTO Plays (id_actor, id_movie, is_main_character)
SELECT Actor.id_actor, Movie.id_movie, Imported.is_main_character
FROM Actor NATURAL JOIN Movie NATURAL JOIN Imported;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Actor` and `Movie` tables are empty. Your natural join will never give any results to be inserted into `Plays` - there's nothing the rows could reference. You will want to fill them with your imported data as well:

```
INSERT INTO Actor (name, fb_likes)
SELECT DISTINCT Imported.name, Imported.fb_likes
FROM Imported;

INSERT INTO Movie (title, duration)
SELECT DISTINCT Imported.title, Imported.duration
FROM Imported;

INSERT INTO Plays (id_actor, id_movie, is_main_character)
SELECT Actor.id_actor, Movie.id_movie, Imported.is_main_character
FROM Imported JOIN Actor USING (name) JOIN Movie USING (title);
```